# How do I fix a page not found error in a Flask app?

Tags: flask, web-applications

I'm new to Flask. I have a site with a number of pages that are working fine. I just tried to add a new one, and it's generating a 404 error. It seems to be set up like all the other pages, so I can't figure out why. Here's the relevant section from the app.py file:

```
@app.route("/verbs")
def verbs():
    return render_template('verbs.html', title="Verbing Out")

@app.route("/tobe")
def toBe():
    return render_template('tobe.html', title="To Be Words")

@app.route("/strategies")
def strategies():
    return render_template('strategies.html', title="Strategies for To Be Words")
```

The files called verbs.html, tobe.html, and strategies.html are in the same directory. the latter two work just fine. verbs.html returns "Not Found. The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again."

All of the files are in the templates directory. Here are the contents of the directory.

```
-rw-r--r--@ 1 Owner  staff  7188 Jul  5 21:32 examples.html
-rw-r--r--@ 1 Owner  staff    65 Jul  4 10:13 footer.html
-rw-r--r--@ 1 Owner  staff   367 Jul  1 12:55 form.html
-rw-r--r--@ 1 Owner  staff   122 Jul  4 10:13 header.html
-rw-r--r--@ 1 Owner  staff  2833 Jul  7 06:42 home.html
-rw-r--r--@ 1 Owner  staff  1537 Jul  4 09:31 layouts.html
-rw-r--r--@ 1 Owner  staff   764 Jul  5 21:20 passive.html
-rw-r--r--@ 1 Owner  staff  1656 Jul  1 12:55 results.html
-rw-r--r--@ 1 Owner  staff  2657 Jul  7 06:47 strategies.html
-rw-r--r--@ 1 Owner  staff     0 Jul  1 12:55 toBeForm.html
-rw-r--r--@ 1 Owner  staff  2991 Jul  5 21:14 tobe.html
-rw-r--r--@ 1 Owner  staff  2185 Jul  5 21:24 verbs.html
```

I'm trying to access them through this navigation menu:

```
 <li><a href="/verbs">Verbing Out</a></li>
 <li><a href="/tobe"> &emsp; To Be Verbs</a></li>
 <li><a href="/strategies"> &emsp; Strategies</a></li>
```

As far as I can see, the three examples are set up in parallel, so I can't figure out why one of them acts differently. What am I missing?

Comment: I've added the code from the navigation menu I'm using for the three files shown. I hope that answers your question.

Comment: If your other routes are rendering perfectly but only one is showing 404 error, please share your templates directory contents

Comment: Sure. Post edited with the directory contents.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is simple. Flask looks for templates in the `templates` directory by default, which is why it doesn't see your files. Put them in the `templates` directory and it will work.

If my explanation seemed tongue-tied, here is a piece of [documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/quickstart/#rendering-templates):

> Flask will look for templates in the templates folder. So if your application is a module, this folder is next to that module, if it's a package it's actually inside your package

Comment: Good point, thank you, but all three files are in the templates directory, so I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: Oh, this is so unexpected! Then you can add the full log here or in the question